# Find dependencies of .Net project

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dependencies

I have a solution with multiple projects. I want to find all dependencies of a particular project such as entities, classes , resources ,... that they are exists in other projects of that solution. I tried Reflector but it does work as that accurate I believe.

Comment: "Find" in what way? If you delete the project and try to rebuild you should get a list of errors about all the missing references.

Comment: Do you mean _dependencies_ or _dependents_? The former can easily be inspected via the the project's "Dependencies" node in the the solution explorer.

Comment: What is the purpose? For any sizable project the number of types that depend on some other project is likely to large to do much with. If you want to a quick and dirty way to check for dependencies for a specific library you could just search for the namespace.

Comment: Solution is a quite large solution, there are many entities and classes in other projects which are used in my target project. I need a way to find all of that entities or classes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use NDepend. First [download NDepend trial](https://www.ndepend.com/download), then [analyze your solution](https://www.ndepend.com/docs/getting-started-with-ndepend#Part2). Then in the [NDepend dependency diagram](https://www.ndepend.com/docs/visual-studio-dependency-graph) right-click the concerned project, then:

- Select Types > that are Using Me Directly
- or Select Types > that I Use Directly

[image: Select dependeny types with NDepend]

Both menus will generate a [C# LINQ code query](https://www.ndepend.com/docs/query-code-with-csharp-linq) and you can then export the matched user types (or used types) to the dependency graph.

[image: dependent types exported to graph]

*Disclaimer: I work at NDepend*